# Как загрузить файл на сайт через Python?

Tags: python, upload

Мне надо загрузить файл на сервер через `Python` (с компьютера, через форму, как клиент, не как сервер). Точнее, я хочу сделать программу, которой на вход дается файл изображения, а возвращается оно же в `ASCII`-коде, через этот сайт: http://photo2text.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из библиотек для работы с HTTP наиболее удобной-человечной является [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html).

Там [загрузка файла](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) выглядит примерно так:

```
# Не тестировалось. Возможно надо будет предварительно сделать GET-запрос
# и вытащить из HTML'я значение поля "VIEWSTATE".
files = {"FileUpload1": ("test.jpeg", open("test.jpeg", "rb"))}
r = requests.post("http://photo2text.com/default.aspx", files=files)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ссылку! Но у меня питон 2.6.6, который не знает такой модуль requests
Что делать тогда, если мне нужно реализовать следующее?
Итак, пользователь заходит по адресу на страницу с формой, один из элементов которой является type=file. С помощью этого элемента выбирает человек файл и нажимает на кнопку отправки его серверу, который его должен получить и хотя бы просто вывести на экран.
Размер файла максимум в пределе 15-20 КБайт
Файл обычный текстовый- "конфиг."
Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы порекомендовал не зависеть от third-party сервисов и использовать возможности библиотек для python. Вот например код, с использованием библиотеки PIL:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

# передача пути к изображению в качестве аргумента командной строки
image_path = sys.argv[1]
img = Image.open(image_path)

# смена разрешения изображения
width, height = img.size
aspect_ratio = height/width
new_width = 120
new_height = aspect_ratio * new_width * 0.55
img = img.resize((new_width, int(new_height)))
# new size of image
# print(img.size)

# перевод изображения в черно-белое
img = img.convert('L')

pixels = img.getdata()

# заменить каждый пиксель изображения на соответствующий ASCII-символ
chars = ["B","S","#","&","@","$","%","*","!",":","."]
new_pixels = [chars[pixel//25] for pixel in pixels]
new_pixels = ''.join(new_pixels)

# разделить строку на одинаковые по длине строки и поместить их в список
new_pixels_count = len(new_pixels)
ascii_image = [new_pixels[index:index + new_width] for index in range(0, new_pixels_count, new_width)]
ascii_image = "\n".join(ascii_image)
print(ascii_image)

# вывести ASCII-изображение в виде текста в файл "ascii_image.txt"
with open("ascii_image.txt", "w") as f:
 f.write(ascii_image)
```

*Источник:* https://dev.to/anuragrana/generating-ascii-art-from-colored-image-using-python-4ace